# Split String in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select query in Postgres with `SPLIT_PART()` function which works fine in postgres

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(totalscore, '_', 1) highlow,
       SPLIT_PART(totalscore, '_', 2) score,
       score_desc
  FROM student_score
 WHERE (totalscore LIKE 'HN%' OR totalscore LIKE 'LN%')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/877966/4

The `SPLIT_PART()` is not working in Oracle
Could please let me know how to achieve the same in Oracle as `SPLIT_PART()`  is not working .

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/042f62/5

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` with `[^_]+` patterns such as

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(totalscore, '[^_]+') AS highlow, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(totalscore, '[^_]+$') AS score,
       score_desc
  FROM student_score
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(totalscore,'^HN_|^LN_')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JzmFkTXy)</kbd>

considering the whole dataset contains one and only one underscore per each value of the column.